# Where does a python descriptor's state go?

Tags: python

#### Background

I'm trying to figure out [Python's descriptors](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors) by reading Lutz's [Learning Python's](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596158068) [section on the topic](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/python/9780596805395/37dot-managed-attributes/957) in which he says: *"Like properties, descriptors are designed to handle specific attributes... Unlike properties, descriptors have their own state..."*

Throughout the chapter he shows examples in which the managed attribute is actually stashed on the containing/wrapping object, as in:

```
def __set__(self, instance, value):
    instance._name = value.lower()
```

I understand these examples and they seem to be common in [write ups](http://martyalchin.com/2007/nov/24/python-descriptors-part-2-of-2/) on the topic. That said, their benefit over [properties](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property) isn't obvious to me and they seem to fall short of the internal state promised in the above quote.

At the end of the chapter he shows an example that is closer to what I pictured after reading "have their own state", as in:

```
def __set__(self, instance, value):
    self.name = value.lower()
```

The example runs but does not do what I'd expect it to do. As [the example](http://pastebin.com/VdCfV5BJ) is a bit long I've put it on Pastebin and added a last line that shows the unexpected behavior (Bob's name is now Sue). Here's a shorter demo snippet:

```
class Wrapper(object):
    class ExampleDescriptor(object):
        def __get__(self, instance, owner):
            print "get %s" % self.state
            return self.state

        def __set__(self, instance, value):
            print "set %s" % value
            self.state = value
    ex = ExampleDescriptor()


w1 = Wrapper()
w1.ex = 1
print w1.ex
w2 = Wrapper()
print w2.ex
w2.ex = 2
print  w1.ex
print w1.ex is w2.ex
```

The output of which is:

```
set 1 
get 1
1
get 1
1
set 2
get 2
2
get 2
get 2
True
```

None of this execution comes as a surprise after looking at the code carefully. The validation logic in the descriptor is making a de facto singleton out of this attribute on the wrapper class; however, it's hard to imagine this shared state was Lutz's intention, or the [intention](http://pastebin.com/ckRKxch7) in this [widely linked tutorial](http://users.rcn.com/python/download/Descriptor.htm#descriptor-example) on the topic.

#### Question

Is it possible to make a descriptor that has internal state that is unique to the wrapping object without stashing that state on the wrapping object instances (as in the first snippet)? Is it possible to modify the `CardHolder` class from the [linked example](http://pastebin.com/VdCfV5BJ) such that Bob does not end up as Sue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Like properties, descriptors are designed to handle specific attributes... Unlike properties, descriptors have their own state..."

I am not sure what point Lutz is trying to make as properties are, in fact, descriptors themselves.

But, even though descriptors do have their own state, it's not widely useful as, as you have discovered, you only get one descriptor object per class attribute instead of one per instance.  This is why the instance is passed in, so that instance-unique values can be saved/accessed.

To prove the point that it is one descriptor object per attribute, you can try this slightly modified code from one of your links:

```
class RevealAccess(object):
    """A data descriptor that sets and returns values
       normally and prints a message logging their access.
    """
    def __init__(self, initval=None, name='var'):
        self.val = initval
        self.name = name
    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
        print 'Retrieving', self.name
        return self.val
    def __set__(self, obj, val):
        print 'Updating' , self.name
        self.val = val

class MyClass(object):
    x = RevealAccess(10, 'var "x"')
    y = RevealAccess(5, 'var "y"')

m = MyClass()
m.x
m.x = 20
m.x
m.y
```

What you should see:

```
Retrieving var "x"
Updating var "x"
Retrieving var "x"
Retrieving var "y"
```

To answer your question:  Yes.  But it's a pain.

```
class Stored(object):
    """A data descriptor that stores instance values in itself.
    """
    instances = dict()
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.instances[self, None] = val
    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
        return self.instances[self, obj]
    def __set__(self, obj, val):
        self.instances[self, obj] = val

class MyClass(object):
    x = Stored(3)
    y = Stored(9)

print(MyClass.x)
print(MyClass.y)
m = MyClass()
m.x = 42
print(m.x)
m.y = 19
print(m.y)
print(m.x)
```

Comment: I think you mean `self.instances[obj]`. Note that you've created a circular reference by storing a reference to an instance within the descriptor. Unless you actually need the instance, you can just store `self.instances[id(obj)]` instead of worrying about weakrefs.

Comment: @MichaelMerickel, actually, I tried that first with the result that both `x` and `y` were the same.  In order to have a unique key both `self` and `obj` are required.  The descriptor is stored on the class, not the instance, so there should be no circular reference.

Comment: @Ethan Thanks. Creating a dict w/in the descriptor class and manually managing state clearly constitutes a _pain_. I guess I'm best off think of properties as an easier api around the core descriptor implementation; instead, of trying to sort out what appears to be two competing ways to do the same thing w/in the language.

Comment: @Finn: properties are the usual route to take, but if/when the time comes that you need more, descriptors are there.

Comment: @MichaelMerickel:  You're right, though, about needing a weakref to not keep the instances alive longer than necessary.

Answer (score 1):

As you've stated already, a descriptor is a class-level instance so its state is shared between each instance of the class.

The descriptor could store an internal hash of instances it's wrapping. To avoid circular references it'd be smarter to have the key be the `id` of the instance. The only reason I'd see to do this is if the descriptor's purpose is to aggregate these properties from different instances.

As for the second part of your question, just do as you stated already and store the underlying state on the instance instead of the descriptor and then Bob will not be Sue.

Comment: > store the underlying state on the instance. Okay then why have a descriptor instead of using properties?

Comment: If by properties you mean the usage of `@property`, hopefully at this point you can understand that itself is a descriptor. Descriptors are heavily used for providing functionality when dealing with both an object and a class because they can tell if `instance is None` in the various calls.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the 2nd sentence?

Comment: A descriptor is defined at the class level, and can be invoked on a class. In this case the `instance` parameter to `__get__`, etc will be `None`. In your linked example `CardHolder.name = 'bob'` is perfectly valid code and any instance of `CardHolder` would now receive `name == 'bob'` because the actual value of `name` is stored on the descriptor instance itself.

Comment: Use a weakref map rather than ids, because the latter are reused after an instance is destroyed.

Comment: Thanks. Can you point me towards source in which descriptors are heavily used on both classes and instances?

Comment: In general, if they are being heavily used on both the class and the instance a metaclass will be used instead because there's probably something going on higher-level than just a single class variable. The descriptor doesn't have access to the class object, only the instances, so it can be hard to share data between different descriptors.

Answer (score 1):

(A complement to other answers)
To attach state to instances you do not control without disturbing them, simply use a weak container; [weakref.WeakKeyDictionary](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/weakref.html#weakref.WeakKeyDictionary) is appropriate here. The garbage collector will make sure that the descriptor's extra state doesn't linger after the instances are collected, and that the descriptor doesn't cause the instances to live longer than they normally would.